# ParseObject.saveAll sometimes results in duplicate objects being created

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a list of 3 ParseObjects and I'm calling saveAll from an Android client:

```
ParseObject.saveAll(myObjectList);
```

I've been testing this over a weak network connection and what I noticed is that sometimes there are duplicate objects created. It's always a multiple of 3. For example, I might get 3, 6, 9, etc... objects saved. The extra objects are duplicates of the originals, meaning they contain the same data except for objectId which is always unique.

Could it be that the weak network connection is leading to some timeout being triggered and saveAll is saving the same 3 objects multiple times? And if so, is there a way to prevent this?

As a workaround, I am manually saving each object individually:

```
for (ParseObject parseObject : myObjectList)
{
    parseObject.save();
}
```